# Want to execute function when press enter key on text field

Tags: ajax, forms, text

I have thi HTML:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <input name="PtName"   type="text" id="PtName" />
  <input name="Button" type="button" id="button"  onclick="search_p()" value="Check" />
        </form>
```

serach_p() is function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function search_p(){
         $.ajax({
      url: 'srchpt.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: { PtName: $('#PtName').val()},
      success: function(data){
        $(".myresult").html(data);
      }
    })
}
</script>
```

I want when I press enter key in PtName text do same search_p() function
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify an `onsubmit` on your form:

```
<form ... onsubmit="search_p(); return false">
```

and change the `type` of your button to `submit`:

```
<input name="Button" type="submit" id="button" value="Check" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using following jquery function:

```
$("#PtName").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        // call function
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript :**
In javascript put the following function

```
function enterPressed(event) {
    var key;

    if (window.event) {
        key = window.event.keyCode; //IE
    } else {
        key = event.which; //firefox
    }

    if (key == 13) {
        yourFunction();
       // do whatever you want after enter pressed event. I have called a javascript function
    }
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="javascript:enterPressed(event)">
```

For required textfield put `onkeypress` event

Answer (score 0):

Call your function on submit event of your form:-

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function search_p(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'srchpt.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { PtName: $('#PtName').val()},
                    success: function(data){
                        $(".myresult").html(data);
                    }
                })
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="" onsubmit="search_p()" >
            <input name="PtName"   type="text" id="PtName" />
            <input name="Button" type="button" id="button"  onclick="search_p()" value="Check" />
        </form>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a textarea that would break-line on **shift+enter**, and on **Enter** would submit:
[This seems to answer my query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18779374/10229006)